# TikZ path controls cause centering to fail

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tikz-path

I have the following figure. It appears to me that the path labelled G messes up the centering of the figure in the document, probably because TikZ uses some invisible control points to draw this arc. (I've let TikZ show the bounding box of the picture to make the problem more evident.) How can I make the actual picture centered?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
            \begin{scope}[local bounding box=a]
                \node (Kinf) {$K_\infty$};
                \node[above of=Kinf, right of=Kinf] (Linf) {$L_\infty$};
                \node[below of=Kinf, right of=Kinf, node distance=4cm] (K0) {$K_{0}$};
                \node[above of=K0, right of=K0] (L0)   {$L_{0}$};
                \draw[-] (Kinf) to node [] {$Z_\infty $} (Linf);
                \draw[-] (Kinf) to node [rotate=-45, midway, above] {$\ldots$} (K0);
                \draw[-] (Linf) to node [rotate=-45, midway, above] {$\ldots$} (L0);
                \draw[-] (K0) to node [] {$Z_0$} (L0);
                \draw (Kinf) to[out=-90, in=180, edge node={node [near start, left] {$\Gamma$}}] (K0);
                \draw[-] (Linf) to[out=0, in=0, looseness=2, edge node={node [near start] {$G$}}] (K0);
            \end {scope}
            \node [fit=(a),inner sep=0pt,draw] {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please give a fully compilable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use of the `bbox` package (see TikZ & PGF manual, v 3.1.5b, *46 Bounding Boxes for Bézier Curves*, page 581):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bbox,
                fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
bezier bounding box=true,  % <---
node distance = 2cm, auto]
        \begin{scope}[local bounding box=a]
            \node (Kinf) {$K_\infty$};
            \node[above of=Kinf, right of=Kinf] (Linf) {$L_\infty$};
            \node[below of=Kinf, right of=Kinf, node distance=4cm] (K0) {$K_{0}$};
            \node[above of=K0, right of=K0] (L0)   {$L_{0}$};
            \draw[-] (Kinf) to node [] {$Z_\infty $} (Linf);
            \draw[-] (Kinf) to node [rotate=-45, midway, above] {$\ldots$} (K0);
            \draw[-] (Linf) to node [rotate=-45, midway, above] {$\ldots$} (L0);
            \draw[-] (K0) to node [] {$Z_0$} (L0);
            \draw (Kinf) to[out=-90, in=180, edge node={node [near start, left] {$\Gamma$}}] (K0);
            \draw[-] (Linf) to[out=0, in=0, looseness=2, edge node={node [near start] {$G$}}] (K0);
        \end {scope}
        \node [fit=(a),inner sep=0pt,draw] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum  & edit:**
slightly different design. In nodes' positioning are used the `positioning` package and syntax, for edge labels are used the `quotes` library. *Also it works without `bbox` library* and code is a bit shortened:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      node distance = 12mm and 11mm,    % <---
                       ]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=a]     % in real document is not needed
    \node (Kinf)                {$K_\infty$};
    \node[above right=of Kinf] (Linf)                   {$L_\infty$};
    \node[below right=24mm and 11 mm of Kinf]   (K0)    {$K_{0}$};
    \node[above right=of K0]   (L0)   {$L_{0}$};
    \draw   (Kinf) to ["$Z_\infty $"]           (Linf) 
            (Kinf) to [sloped, "$\ldots$"]      (K0) 
            (Linf) to [sloped, "$\ldots$"]      (L0)
            (K0)   to ["$Z_0$"]                 (L0)
    (Kinf) to[out=240, in=180, "$\Gamma$" ']    (K0)
    (Linf) to[out=345, in=0,   
              looseness=1.5,  "$G$"]    (K0);
\end{scope}                             
\node[fit=(a),inner sep=0pt,draw=teal] {};  % in real document is not needed
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Warning:*
The first solution will not work with new version of TikZ, i.e. with version 3.1.6, because as stated in [github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/releases/tag/3.1.6](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/releases/tag/3.1.6):

> The bbox library introduced in PGF 3.1.5 was removed because the author decided to impose restrictions on redistribution which violates freedoms 2 and 3 of the Free Software Definition, making it effectively non-free which is in contradiction with the GPLv2 + LPPLv1.3c terms that PGF/TikZ is distributed under. I further recommend that if there are files containing bbox code left over from a previous version that these are removed to avoid potential legal issues.

Note: the second answer in addendum not use `bbox` library, so it will works in new version of TikZ/PGF package too. See @Torbjørn T. comments below answer (thank you very much for info).

Comment: Note that the `bbox` library was removed from TikZ with version 3.1.6 due to licensing issues: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/releases/tag/3.1.6

Comment: @TorbjørnT., hank you for info. I still have version 3.1.5b (which is now available).  When new version will be available?  What to do now? Add a note to the answer, that use of answer is on risk of user? Or that it will not work anymore? Or just delete answer?

Comment: It's available on GitHub, but I don't know when it will make its way to CTAN. The code will still work for those with 3.1.5, so perhaps just add a note that it will stop working if/when one upgrades to 3.1.6. In your second code it isn't that much of a problem though, so you could remove `bbox` from that.

Answer (score 1):

The bbox library allows you to calculate the smallest bounding box that contains the figure with the option `bezier bounding box=true`.

Instead of using the `fit` library to frame this figure, I used the `current bounding box` dimensions. And since this box is too narrow on the right side (it is tangent to the frame), I made it slightly larger.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary {fit}
\usetikzlibrary{bbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto,bezier bounding box=true]
        \begin{scope}%[local bounding box=a]
            \node (Kinf) {$K_\infty$};
            \node[above of=Kinf, right of=Kinf] (Linf) {$L_\infty$};
            \node[below of=Kinf, right of=Kinf, node distance=4cm] (K0) {$K_{0}$};
            \node[above of=K0, right of=K0] (L0)   {$L_{0}$};
            \draw[-] (Kinf) to node [] {$Z_\infty $} (Linf);
            \draw[-] (Kinf) to node [rotate=-45, midway, above] {$\ldots$} (K0);
            \draw[-] (Linf) to node [rotate=-45, midway, above] {$\ldots$} (L0);
            \draw[-] (K0) to node [] {$Z_0$} (L0);
            \draw (Kinf) to[out=-90, in=180, edge node={node [near start, left] {$\Gamma$}}] (K0);
            \draw[-] (Linf) to[out=0, in=0, looseness=2, edge node={node [near start] {$G$}}] (K0);
        \end {scope}
%        \node [fit=(a),inner sep=0pt,draw] {};
        \draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle
([xshift=5pt]current bounding box.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat The `bbox` library is written anonymously, and in any case people can use open-source code however they wish

Comment: @JosephWright This is true but "The bbox library makes it possible to disregard control points in the calculation" is a misleading statement. This is not an appropriate description of what the library does. The library establishes the correct bounding box, which is *not* achieved by (just) disregarding the control points.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I updated my answer, `The bbox library allows you to calculate the smallest bounding box that contains the figure`

Comment: I feel the very least you could do is to acknowledge in the answer that you got told by others that the answer was not entirely correct. The cleaner way IMHO would be to remove the post altogether, an earlier answer already pointed out that the `bbox` library can be used here.